# DynamicRouteValueTransformer changing values doesn't have any effects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I am trying to create a webapi that uses plugins for the endpoint handling

i have a calculate controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CalculateController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{functionName}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string functionName)
    {
      /// some logic here  
    }
}
```

this should respond to  /api/calculate/house

i have added a TranslationTransformer to the startup and i see it gets activated

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //hidden for abbreviate 
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>("api/{controller}/{**action}");
    });
}
```

i implemented some logic that can alter the values in the translationtransformer

```
public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    RouteConfig dynamicRoute =  GetDynamicRoute(values);

    if (dynamicRoute != null)
    {
        values["controller"] = dynamicRoute.Controller;
        values["action"] = dynamicRoute.Action;
    }

    return values;
}
```

testing results:

**testcase 1**

/api/calculate/House

start TranslationTransformer 
values["controller"] : "calculate"
values["action"] : "House"

no change result controller gets activated :**OK**

**testcase2**

/api/demo/fake

start TranslationTransformer 
values["controller"] : "demo"
values["action"] : "fake"

no change result controller doesn't get activated : **OK**

**testcase3**

/api/demo/fake

start TranslationTransformer 
values["controller"] : "demo"
values["action"] : "fake"

Change 
values["controller"] : "calculate"
values["action"] : "House"

result controller doesn't get activated : **not OK**

**testcase 4**

/api/calculate/House

start TranslationTransformer 
values["controller"] : "calculate"
values["action"] : "House"

Change 
values["controller"] : "demo"
values["action"] : "fake"

result controller gets activated : **not OK**

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was missing.

Apparently the values ​​are not the only elements that determine the selection of controllers. This was shown in test case 4

So you can just blindly adopt the values ​​of a valid request.

The value for the controller and the action are actually the names ​​of the controller and the method that is needed to be activated.

In my case it was  controller:  Calculate. But as action the name of the method had to be : Get

I still find it a bit puzzling why changing the names to the values of a valid request would not result in the same behavior.